# Catching errors inside of web worker inside of eval inside of async function?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, async-await

I use a web worker to run user supplied code. For that I use `eval` inside of the worker.

When the user passes in an async function, which he then calls, the error handler does not trigger:

```js
const workerScript = async () => {
  const userCode = `(async () => { throw new Error("blah"); })();`;

  eval(userCode);
};

const blob = new Blob(["(", workerScript, ")();"], { type: "text/javascript"});
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
const worker = new Worker(url);

worker.addEventListener("error", (event) => {
  console.log("yay, I want to be here!");
});
```

I want to catch all errors thrown in the `eval`, it's also fine to catch all errors thrown in the entire worker.

The code above does not work, what am I doing wrong?

Isn't the `error` event supposed to fire on all errors that happen inside of the worker?

How would I do this correctly?

Comment: Note that there is `window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', /*...*/)`, but i am unsure, whether it carries over from the web-worker, or whether you'll have to add that there, and manually catch, serialize, and transmit the error to the main thread, to handle it there.

Comment: I can add the listener inside of the worker, however, `e.preventDefault()` doesn't seem to prevent the error from showing up in the browser console.

Comment: @ASDFGerte - Well observed. `Worker` objects get their `error` semantics from `AbstractWorker`, which [doesn't seem to have that (yet?)](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#the-abstractworker-mixin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic issue here is that the code doesn't throw an error, it gets a promise (from the `eval`) that it never checks the rejection of. So it gets an unhandled rejection rather than an error.

You can handle that rejection by using `try`/`catch` around the `eval` call and using `await` on it. Then the question becomes, what to do with the error. <s>I don't think a worker can raise an `error` event for the parent, so I'd probably send a message that identifies itself as an error instead, like this (see comments).</s> See update below, between the two of us we got there.

Originally I did the `try`/`catch` thing around the `await eval` with sending the `type: "error"` message, but you've mentioned that the "user code" might fail to handle rejections in ways you can't control. In that case, you can use the worker's [`unhandledrejection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unhandledrejection_event) event (from within the worker).

Here's an example with the custom message, but below I'll incorporate your trick for using `error` instead:

```
const workerScript = async () => {
    // Catch unhandled rejections, turn them into messages of type "error"
    self.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", event => {
        postMessage({type: "error", error: event.reason});
        event.preventDefault();
    });
 
    const userCode = `(async () => { throw new Error("blah"); })();`;
  
    eval(userCode);
};

const workerCode = `(${workerScript})();`;
const blob = new Blob([workerCode], { type: "text/javascript"});
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
const worker = new Worker(url, {type: "module"});

// A reusable handler for the various paths errors might take
const workerError = error => {
    console.log("yay, I want to be here!", error);
};

// Handle both the `error` event and the `message` event with `type: "error"`
worker.addEventListener("error", workerError);
worker.addEventListener("message", event => {
    if (event.data && event.data.type === "error") {
        workerError(event.data.error);
    }
});
```

But now that we have non-`async` that gets the rejection, we can trigger the `error` event by re-throwing the rejection reason, as you pointed out in a comment:

```
const workerScript = async () => {
    // Catch unhandled rejections, turn them into messages of type "error"
    self.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", event => {
        // Prevent this being reported (Firefox doesn't currently respect this)
        event.preventDefault();

        // Throwing here will trigger the worker's `error` event, since this
        // isn't `async` code and nothing handles it
        throw event.reason;
    });
 
    const userCode = `(async () => { throw new Error("blah"); })();`;
  
    eval(userCode);
};

const workerCode = `(${workerScript})();`;
const blob = new Blob([workerCode], { type: "text/javascript"});
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
const worker = new Worker(url, {type: "module"});

// Handle errors
worker.addEventListener("error", event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("yay, I want to be here!", event.message);
});
```

Comment: What if the user nests async function calls inside of other async function calls without awaiting? the await before the eval only handles the outer most async function. If the user does not pass an async function, will there be an error because of the await?

Comment: @swift-lynx - I've updated the answer to have the worker handle `unhandledrejection` instead, converting it to an error it can send the parent.

Comment: This handles all of my cases now. Thank you. For some reason, the console still says `Error: blah`. I'd like to not have any errors in the console, how can I prevent this? It seems to me that the `event.preventDefault()` inside of the `unhandledrejection` doesn't work?

Comment: @swift-lynx - I suspect you're using Firefox, which doesn't respect the `preventDefault`. Chromium and its variants (Chrome, Brave, Edge) all do.

Comment: I found out that you can throw the error inside of the `unhandledrejection` listener like so `throw event.reason;` to get it picked up by the `error` listener on the worker. That way you can remove the entire if inside of the `message` event. And yes, I'm using FF, so I'll have to live with it still printing the error... Thank you for helping ;)

Comment: @swift-lynx - Doh! I should have thought of that! Since that handler isn't `async` code, an unhandled error there is...an unhandled error. :-) I'm going to *have* to remember that trick. I updated the answer for others.